# How to use QNetworkManager for REST api?

Tags: c++, qt, rest, network-programming

I would like to make a class for accessing data via REST API, for example:

```
class MeteoStation{
   int getLatestTemperature();
   int getLatestPessure();
   private:
   QNetworkManager nmng;
}
```

How could I implement this methods? Usually I was using something like:

```
   int MeteoStation::getLatestTemperature(){    
      ...
      QEventLoop eventLoop;
      connect(&m_nam,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),&eventLoop,SLOT(quit()));
      QNetworkReply *reply = m_nam.get( req );
      eventLoop.exec();
      reply->readAll()
      ...
    }
```

But since using inner QEventLoop is not recommended, how should I see to whom the response belong to?

```
MeteoStation::MeteoStation(){
   connect(&nmam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                     this, SLOT(parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void MeteoStation::parseNetworkResponse( QNetworkReply *finished )
{
   QByteArray data = finished->readAll();
...
```

Yes and it would be nice to have the class thread save. How are you solving that in your code?

How bad is making the call synchronous with:

```
QNetworkRequest req(url);
QScopedPointer<QNetworkReply> reply(nam.get(req));

QTime timeout= QTime::currentTime().addSecs(10);
while( QTime::currentTime() < timeout && !reply->isFinished()){
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}

if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
    qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
}
QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
```

Comment: "how should I see to whom the response belong to?" - Return the pointer to the created QNetworkReply object to the caller of getLatestTemperature. The caller can then connect to its finished() signal. You can wrap that into another command pattern style class if you want to encapsulate error handling or reply parsing.

Comment: That's good idea connection to the  QNetworkReply object instead. It's solving the problem: "how should I see to whom the response belong to?" Now the waiting for response? Imagine that the `int MeteoStation::getLatestTemperature()` was originally reading temperature value from some memory mapped register and now should get the value from REST. Could I just somehow modify the class MeteoStation (in library) or do I have to redesign the app?

Comment: I think it's futile and error-prone to hide asynchronous behavior behind a synchronous API: 1) using local event loops is the root of many evils and to be avoided 2) you probably don't want to block the caller (e.g. in the UI thread) while waiting for the network response to come in. I think you should redesign the app to assume asynchronous communication. It will prevent many serious headaches in the long run.

Comment: Well, I've dug out in Qt PostgreSQL and C++ CouchDB drivers and they are both blocking the caller for query result. Postgresql in a loop and Pillowtalk for curl. Synchronous calls can be evil but they are widely used also in Qt code. Redesigning the whole app is out of the option. For example I could not simply break the class init() method into startInit(), continueInitWithTemperature(), continueInitWithPressure() and this every time I'm asking the REST server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved my problem using QCoreApplication::processEvents(). The response is there within ms and I'm able to implement functionality close to libcurl.

```
QNetworkRequest req(url);
QScopedPointer<QNetworkReply> reply(nam.get(req));

QTime timeout= QTime::currentTime().addSecs(10);
while( QTime::currentTime() < timeout && !reply->isFinished()){
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}

if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
    qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
}
QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Qt docs should provide all info you need.
You creat a nam, connect the finished signal, send the request.

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
```

Detecting to which request a reply belongs should not be too hard. The reply contains the url. It might be different, but not **that** different:

> ...but for a variety of reasons it can be different (for example, a
>   file path being made absolute or canonical).

**QUrl QNetworkReply::url() const**

> Returns the URL of the content downloaded or uploaded. Note that the
>   URL may be different from that of the original request.

Comment: I see your point with parsing the request url from the response but that does not look like a nice way of doing that. Could you direct me how can I make the method `int MeteoStation::getLatestTemperature()`? Or is (getter method) sign of wrong app design and should be **always** done like `void MeteoStation::requestLatestTemperature()`  and then handling the response in a slot?

Comment: Nothing much to help. I don't know your data. Generally it does not really matter, if you use my or  Frank Osterfeld's appoach. As soon as the data comes it, the handling is the same. `int MeteoStation::getLatestTemperature()` is hardly usable for asynchronous requests. `void MeteoStation::requestLatestTemperature()` is (IMHO) the only sensible way to go.

Comment: Data are in CouchDB server so pretty fast available. When using MySQL native library I'm also not getting response from the server as signal. What I would like to is just having HTTP request synchronous.

Comment: Regardless how fast your CouchDB responses come, they are still asynchronous. To hammer them into a synchronous design is a pain in the neck. You tried this with a local event loop... Bad idea. I don't know, how to do something like that in a clean way. And you cannot compare CouchDB server with MySQL server... totally different architecture.

Comment: You are right, basically every access to outside program data is asynchronous: database, samba share.. Even filesystem is. And for all this we have synchronous(looking) methods. So is there a way for doing HTTP requests synchronously and cleanly?

Comment: Some classes have waitfor* functions. As far as I know, the QNetworkAccessManager has not. So _I think_, it can only be used asynchronously. If you want to do HTTP requests synchronously, you probably have to do it low level with QTcpSockets. But I have the feeling you desperately try to avoid asynchronous coding. You should not. Takes some time to get used to it, but it is worth the effort.

Comment: Here, found this to make QNAM synchronous: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/484905/Use-QNetworkAccessManager-for-synchronous-download  Personally I would not touch this with a ten foot pole.... without a **very** good reason.

Comment: You are right that codeproject.com is using local QEventLoop in obfuscated way and I'm trying not to change much in to project just switch to more external data source. Probably using QTcpSockets or linking with library such a libcurl is the way to go.